# How to write a method that runs another method received as parameter in Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7, android-espresso

I have some methods like

```
public static ViewInteraction findView(int id) {
    return onView(allOf(withId(id), isDisplayed()));
}

public static ViewInteraction findView(int id, int index){
    return onView(allOf(withIndex(withId(id), index), isDisplayed()));
}

public static ViewInteraction findView(int id, String text) {
    return onView(allOf(withText(text), withId(id)));
}

public static ViewInteraction findView(String text) {
    return onView(allOf(withText(text), isDisplayed()));
}
```

These methods search for something and when not found throw an exception.

What i'd like to do is write a method that runs any of these methods so I can try to find something many times before finally throwing the exception. Along these methods are other 10 more or so.

I tried using the Strategy Pattern and the Command Pattern but either they didn't work for me or I didn't know how to implement them. If the solution is one of those, could you point me to a clear explanation or do it in the answer?

I searched for tutorials of them but all were really brief and I'm no senior developer to understand right away.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be best to post the code that you have of how these methods are used and what is the desired result.

Comment: That depends on what that methods do. If they basically do the same thing but operate on different fields you might want to pass some object that describes your "query". That object could contain fields like `text` and the type could either be something nullable (where `null` would mean "don't use it") or `Optional<T>` (where `isPresent()` returns false to indicate it shouldn't be used) or something else. That way you'd probably not need to call multiple methods at all but do it in one swoop - again: provided that they are very similar.

Comment: Updated the question with the exact methods. They are used to find views with espresso.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your searching methods take some time to complete. If so, or if there are many of them, then you probably should use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), which came with Java7, [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) all tasks wrapped as [Callables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and then keep polling each [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) (using [get(long, TimeUnit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) with a short timeout) until you get a usable result or stop after some general timeout (you need to implement the latter yourself, but that's easy with [System.nanoTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())). You can wrap your methods like so:

```
Callable<ViewInteraction> method1 = new Callable<ViewInteraction>() {
    @Override
    public ViewInteraction call() throws Exception {
        return findView(id, text);
    }
};
```

Just for completeness, in Java 8 you'd rather do

```
Callable<ViewInteraction> method2 = () -> findView(id, text);
```

This way, you can run all methods concurrently (you can choose how many threads are processing your callables, so you can start with 1 and increase parallelism later, when everything gets more complex). Note that `get()` will throw an [ExecutionExceptionn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) in case your `findView()` method thew an exception.

If that's too complex, you still can use the Callables for implementing your Command pattern.